# Mocking msg.sender during unit test

Tags: solidity, remix, testing, unittesting

I am currently trying to push my unit testing far in order to achieve a complete coverage over my code.
I am using Open Zepplin's [`Ownable.sol`](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/v2.0.0/contracts/ownership/Ownable.sol) contract and I cannot find in the documentation something about mocking the user sending the request (understand `msg.sender`) using `remix_test.sol`.

Do any of you ever heard about or have done such a thing ?

Comment: I think Ownable got deleted in the latest release because it was unsecure, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can use real address as msg.sender, you don't need any mocking here. Please refer to Open Zeppelin unit-test code for further information

https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/test/ownership/Ownable.test.js

For test on remix you can refer to sample test from remix ide

https://github.com/ethereum/remix/blob/master/remix-tests/tests/various_sender/sender_test.sol

Hope this might help!

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer ! It appears to me that these tests are not written with `remix_tests.sol`, but Mocha. I was wondering if there is a way to write them down using Remix only.

Comment: I think we can use some default account of remix when you selecting run on Javascript VM

Comment: Yeah, but it seems you cannot switch during the test...
So when I launch using let's call it `A` user, the contract is supposed to be owned by `A`.
When I start the test again changing to `B` user, the contract is supposed to be owned by `B`.

Comment: you can use specific account like this from remix sample test code

https://github.com/ethereum/remix/blob/master/remix-tests/tests/various_sender/sender_test.sol

Comment: Hmm, sorry but I don't think this is the answer to what I asked... Indeed, this allow me to get existing test accounts, but this doesn't allow my unit test to launch a function **as if I was `TestsAccounts.getAccount(1)`**.